# Caesar Cipher - Wraparound Method for ASCII Characters More Confusing via Textbook

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

I understand the Caesar Cipher method and have successfully written my own wraparound using a modulo operator, but I do not understand the method shown in my formal study textbook. I am referring to the code I have commented below:

```
plainText = input("Enter a one-word, lowercase message: ")
distance = int(input("Enter the distance value: "))
code = ""
for ch in plainText:
    ordvalue = ord(ch)
    cipherValue = ordvalue + distance
    #confusion begins here
    if cipherValue > ord('z'):
        cipherValue = ord('a') + distance - \
            (ord('z') - ordvalue + 1)
    #confusion ends here
    code += chr(cipherValue)
print(code)
```

Comment: That code is a bit confusing, but the last part is how many characters you are before 'a'. E.g. if you put in 'x', the last part works out to 3, indicating 'x' is 3 characters before 'a' (when you wrap around). I had to try a few examples before it made sense.

Comment: Hmm...I understand what you're saying, but that still seems like a relative shift that needs to be made in regards to ord('a'), is that not true?

Comment: Try input 'x' with distance 4, for example. If you start at 'a', add the distance 4, and then go back 3 (the distance between 'x' and 'a'), you get the right answer 'b'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes sense if you think about it even though it's a slightly verbose and complicated way to calculate it. Alas, there is no limit to how complicated you can make any expression, only to how simple you can make it.

So `ord('a')` and `ord('z')` have values 97 and 122. When we get `ord(char) + distance = 123,` we want to map it back to `ord('a')`, right. So we then need to subtract the length of the allowed interval of characters. This interval has size `ord('z') - ord('a') + 1` (+1 since both endpoints are actually part of the interval and allowed values).

The resulting formula would then be (assuming `ordValue + distance > ord('z')`)

```
cipherValue = ordValue + distance - (ord('z') - ord('a') + 1) 
            = ordValue + distance - ord('z') + ord('a') - 1
            = ord('a') + distance - ord('z') + ordValue - 1
            = ord('a') + distance - (ord('z') - ordValue + 1)
```

... which is the expression that confuses you.

Finally, this method has the pitfall that it only covers overflow with at most `ord('z') - ord('a') + 1` so if `distance` is longer than that, it wouldn't work:

```
cipherValue = ordValue + distance - (ord('z') - ord('a') + 1) 
            = ordValue + (ord('z') - ord('a') + 2) - ord('z') + ord('a') - 1
            = ordValue + ord('z') - ord('a') + 2 - ord('z') + ord('a') - 1
            = ordValue + 1
```

Now, if `ordValue` comes from `ord('z')`, then we are in trouble since the cipher value would be `ord('z') + 1 = 123` which does not correspond to a character in the cipher text alphabet (`chr(123) = '{'`).

Perhaps we can assume that `distance` shouldn't be that long or longer (it makes sense), otherwise a modulo expression would be safer to use.